# Display options for FK select - Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, html-select

How do I display the options for the foreign key select element (drop-down) in a more meaningful way than `<class name> object`?

Here's a picture of what isn't so helpful:

[image]

Some info:

Bar has FK to Foo. FooSerializer defines Foo.create and Foo.update, for nested write.

When I go to /bar/, I can select a Foo for the FK. When I save the bar, it will point to the Foo. This is using a select element in the form, from the template packs select.html.

The issue however, is that all of the select options are "Foo object". How should I proceed if I want to make these instances of "Foo object" into a meaningful custom representation, i.e. "Foo - pk: 1, value: 123". I am using the Browseable API renderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For client side representation you can implement `__str__`:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on python 3.7, django 2.0.7, djangorestframework  3.8.2. Seems its picking its own value which is  `<PK> object`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a `__unicode__` or `__str__` method on your Foo model?